# Sequence of Verb Tenses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I wonder are these both sentences correct?

1. My home became empty since you walked away.
2. My home has become empty since you walked away.

Is the choice stylistic? Or I need to use only one of them and the other doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example sentences

> My home **became empty** since you walked away.
>   My home **has become empty** since you walked away.

both have the same meaning, that

> *From the time you walked away, my home is now empty.*

To this native speaker's ear, there may be a nuance in what you are trying to say.  Your original sentences might have the meaning that *after* you walked away the house was then *emptied (of furniture)*.

If instead you wanted to say that the person who left took all the joy with them, you might say

> My home **has been empty since** you walked away.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to say that all the joy and the happiness are gone after he/she left the home. Thanks!!

Comment: @LexRomah Please accept this as your answer.